Vite React.js app on Kubernetes container having ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout) erro
I am having this problem for some time now and what ever I try to do it seems to not change a thing.
I have a container running an Reactjs Javascript app, created with Vite and it works perfect on my computer. Never had errors on deployment. Now I tried to upload to a Kubernetes Cluster as a Docker container and it's giving me an 504 ERR_ABORTED (Gateway Timeout) on different Vite dependencies, the more frequent are: react, react-router-dom, react_jsx-dev-runtime, react-dom_client. And then some times it appears chunk and other dependecies, but normally not as common. The weird part is that sometimes, almost never, the page is succefully loaded and those errors doesn't appear, but as soon as I refresh the page it goes back to not working.
I already seen a lot of solutions online, but nothing seems to work.
Here it is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:18.17.0-alpine
COPY ./src /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip  make g++
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install
RUN npm update
#RUN npm rebuild --verbose sharp
RUN npm rebuild
RUN npm run build
RUN node ./node_modules/esbuild/install.js
#CMD npm run dev
#CMD npx vite dev --force -- --host
CMD npm run dev -- --host
#CMD npm run dev -- --host

I already tried different commands to expose, I commented some tests.
Here it is my vite.config:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
  /*server: {
    host: true,
    port: 5173
  }*/
})

I already tried to put this part in there with the dependencies, but it didn't work:
optimizeDeps: {
  exclude: [...]
}

I made a Pull from the code that was giving the error on production and removed the node-modules on my computer to see if it would give me the same errors and run the commands on the Dockerfile and the errors didn't appeared. So I am stuck with an App that works on my computer, but not on the Kubernetes Cluster on my Server.
Any idea or solutions for my problem?
Thank you very much!
